# How can I use OpenMP directives inside functions?

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm trying to parallelise several functions with OpenMP directives but' there are some problems with it.

The idea is to create a parallel region only once and invoke functions after it. Only one thread invokes function (#pragma omp single) and after it inside a function multiply threads start working (#pragma omp for). I rewrote the code but it doesn't work at all. I would be happy if you have some ideas how to fix the problem.

```
int main() 
{
    size_t rows = 3, cols = 3;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> A, B, C, TrA;
    fillMatrix(A, rows, cols, 1.0);
    fillMatrix(B, rows, cols, 2.0);



    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            multiplyMatrix(A, B, C);
        }
    }


    showMatrix(A);
    showMatrix(B);
    showMatrix(C);


    return 0;
}


void multiplyMatrix(
        const std::vector<std::vector<double>> &A,
        const std::vector<std::vector<double>> &B,
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> &C) {

        C.assign(A.size(), std::vector<double>(B[0].size()));

        #pragma omp for schedule(static)
        for (size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i) {
          for (size_t j = 0; j < B[0].size(); ++j) {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < B.size(); ++k) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're almost there. Remove the `single` directive from `main()` and put it just before the `C.assign()` call in `multiplyMatrix()` and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks, Gilles! You helped me to solve this problem. But what's wrong was with my approach?

Comment: @Rumato In your approach, only a single thread invoked `multiplyMatrix`. The other threads did not reach the `omp for` clause. It would work only with _nested parallelism_.

Comment: For lucifer's sake, please just stop trying to multiply matrices on your own. This is one of the most discussed topics on the internet. Just use OpenBLAS or some other BLAS library. You will NEVER beat such a library in performance. Besides, please also stop using `vector<vector<>>` for matrices. This is way slower than a 1-dimensional array due to CPU caching issues. Every beginner falls into the same trap.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I completely agree on matrix multiplication (and other BLAS functions), but it may not be Rumato who is misguided. Many courses seem to use matrix-multiplication as an example/homework for their students. IMO that's only reasonable if you give full marks to someone whose homework solution is "I called the BLAS library" :-)

Comment: @JimCownie You may be right. However, the fact that he's using OpenMP for that kind of task told me he's not likely to be doing a homework.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I have seen matrix multiplication used as a sample problem in OpenMP courses :-(